# Override GCC compile flags

Tags: gcc

Is it possible to override the runtime-detect flags in **make/configure/cmake** to detect the architecture optimization level and override it?

For example **./configure** & **make** will detect a modern CPU with SSE for example, I would like to override that and set: when gcc compiles an .cpp file, it will always use **-march=i586**

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

./configure --help

Will help you

```
Some influential environment variables:
CXX         C++ compiler command
CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
          nonstandard directory <lib dir>
LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
          you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
CC          C compiler command
CFLAGS      C compiler flags
CPP         C preprocessor
CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
```

CFLAGS=" " ./configure

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a more global approach. A build server needs to rebuild a big repository with a lot of modules (>30) and I at best would not like to change every step... instead force **gcc** at **-march=i586** instead... if thats possible. And sometimes **cmake** is used instead of configure

Comment: Actually can you be more specific about your task? It sounds like you writing a packet manager. Are you sure you want such optimization?

Comment: I check-out a middleware repository containing multiple modules, I do one *make all* and later get an middleware lib/include package containing all that middleware which can be used for (related) projects. But now the target platform has changed and everything needs to be built with **-march=i586**. I would love to override all further gcc/g++ calls to use **-march=i586**

Comment: export CFLAGS="-march=i586" no? This is not a stackoverflow question then - this a question related to the basics of *nix.

Comment: Do an `export CFLAGS=""` before starting your batch make commands?

Answer (score 0):

Every configure script is different, there is no magic bullet. If you want to reliably override the gcc compiler flags, create a wrapper script for /usr/bin/gcc and add/modify the flags you want, and put your script at the start of your PATH.

You could use export CC & CXX to point to your gcc wrapper script, but I've seen scripts which predicate on 'if CC == "gcc"', which would break.

Comment: How should be named this wrapper script: should have the same name as the gcc executable that should be invoked?